# Find if Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (VC10) x64 is installed from registry or filesystem

Tags: batch-file, 64-bit, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a **batch** file and I need to know if **Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (VC10) x64** is installed before starting some applications that requires it. What places from the registry or the filesystem could confirm me that it is installed?

Comment: [This may help as a starting point](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **[HOWTO: Detect installed Visual Studio editions, packages or service packs](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx)**

You may find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/05/04/detection-keys-for-net-framework-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx) helpful for you.

> The detection keys for Visual Studio are used both to detect if the
>   product is installed and what service pack level is installed. As with
>   previous versions, these keys and values are under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing.
>
> Key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\$(var.ProductEdition)\$(var.LCID)**
>
> Name  Install
>
> Type  REG_DWORD (32-bit integer)
>
> Data  0x00000001 (1)

Comment: On 64-bit systems, you may need to also check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS` if doing so from a 64-bit process.

Comment: Both links are broken now  Is it possible to fix them?  (I upvoted so I think I deserve working links ).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over every single key under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

And look in the **DisplayName (REG_SZ)** registry.

This is where the Program and Features application gets the information to populate the list of all software currently installed on Windows.